# Attempting to set location in String Array, getting out of bounds exception thrown

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm trying to 'add' to my `String[]`.

I'm reading a file with a `BufferedFileReader`.  I have my code set up to return a `String[]`, lets call it `list`.  Essentially my code loops through the file until it's empty (well `null`), adds each line to a `string`, then out of the loop I `split()` the `string` into my `list`.

I fear that because I do that the `list` has an `immutable` size, which is why I'm getting the `Exception` thrown.

How do I go about writing the following code the 'correct' way?

---

#### Code

<sub>note the `list` below isn't `instantiated` like that, just for labeling purposes.</sub>

```
String[] list;
int length = list.length;
list[length + 1] = (method that returns a string);
list[length + 2] = (method that returns a string);
```

It goes on for 5 spaces.

I'm going about this because I'm attempting to save fields to a file, and in order to avoid overwriting a file I'd like to add to it instead.

---

### TL;DR:

Essentially trying to add to a `String[]` or find a better alternative because I can't change the length.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not so Clear.

If I am correct you want to define array size by dynamically

You better use `java.util.ArrayList` .. Where you can dynamically change the length of the `Array` .

Comment: Sorry as soon as I asked the question the answer hit me.

So yes, I need to use Array Lists.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> String[] or find a better alternative because I can't change the
>   length.

You better use ArrayList for this.

```
ArrayList<String> ar=new ArrayList<String>(put capacity if you want);
```

you can remove search in arraylist easily.

Comment: Wish I could take my question back, it came to me as soon as I posted.

Thanks, array lists shall be it.  Though I can't do exactly that, going to have to convert back and forth in the class that has the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("hello");
list.add("world");

return list.toArray();
```